# Collision Objects losing their effect

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I have a scene where I have a flag blowing, and a box with a collision modifier on it. Everything is working fine, but every time i disable the collision object from the view port, they lose their effect...

How should I be doing this to where I don't lose my objects, but I just don't see them?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.. I was pressing the "disable in viewports" instead of "hide in viewports" ... it seems to be working now.